# How to Add user to XP Machine for authentication for a network

Tags: windows-xp, networking, login, authentication

I am getting a lot of popups for password when I access the other PC. I would like to add my credentials to that other PC so the popup disappears? How do I do it?

Note: I am not talking about adding a general user (control panel -> Users). I am talking about network authentication and profiles :)

Comment: What are you doing when you "access the other PC"? Are you connecting with Remote Desktop? Are you viewing files through the network? Or something else?

Comment: I am hosting a website which I am accessing from other PCS on the local network. The popup should not appear. It is Peer-to-Pear network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the security of the resource you are trying to access, if its a file share and the share permissions are set for local users/authenticated users etc.. then you would need a local account on that machine, Alternatively if its a wide open share ie. the everyone object is the security tab of the file share and everyone has full access you shouldn't need a user account.

> I am not talking about adding a general user (control panel -> Users).
>   I am talking about network authentication and profiles :)

Theres no duality in windows between the two unless you use **Active Directory** ,all you have is local windows accounts, unless your referring to  FTP or some over network protocol

Comment: So there is no easy way to specifically identify the user you want to share your folder with on network?

Comment: Yes but you'll will be specifying a windows user or a windows object such as "authenticated users" "administrator" etc.. and they have to be on the machine serving the share, I must stress this is only for windows related stuff SMB etc... if you are using other protocols I know some FTP servers let you authenticate against a text file, be nice to know exactly what your accessing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, windows networking isn't as easy as it could be, especially in XP. (Homegroup on Windows 7 really helps!).

Creating a user with the same username and password on the other machine(s) really is the only way to logon straight away without asking for usernames and passwords.

Alternatively, if you do not want to be prompted for credentials, I would recommend ticking the "Remember my password" box.

[image]

Comment: This is really is a weird solution, isn't it. And a Security hole if this did work. But yes I did try "Remember my password" and even that I get even more popups. Bravo Microsoft.

Comment: @Dave - how is it a security hole?

Answer (score 1):

Wel if your network is a workgroup sort, then you have to create an account on the server that controls the workgroup. If its a domain sort of network, well create and account on a server controlling the domain using AD. That should work as i have done it several times in both environments.